# Associate a letter with a cell (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with different elements, let's say something along these lines (table from A1 to C2):

```
A  B  C
13 56 120
```

Is there a way how I can write in another cell "=A+B+C" and get the result of 13+56+120=189? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify your range please just so there are no misunderstandings. Your current table layout suggests it's actually A1 to C2 instead of A1 to B3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a **Name** to a cell and then use that **Name** in other formulas.

Click on **A1**

Then click in the Name Box and enter:

A + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This give the cell **A1** the **Name** A

Elsewhere you can enter formulas like:

```
=A + 15
```